# how to connect to published website on remote server IIS

Tags: iis, remote-access

I have published folder of my website. On remote server in IIS,I add new website and application pool. Also I wrote host name "`ccportal-ivr.com`" of my site in file "`hosts`",which locate in:
 `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

```
  127.0.0.1       ccportal-ivr.com
```

What I need to configure, if I need to enter to my website from my local PC(only write in browser ip of remote server)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `hosts` entry will direct all requests to `ccportal-ivr.com` to `127.0.0.1`, which is your machine's local address. Since your site is on a remote server, you should either put that server's IP address in your `hosts` file instead, or just leave `hosts` alone and enter the server's IP address in your browser's address bar.